# Problemas añadiendo meses a fecha en PHP

Tags: php, html, html5, date

Basicamente tengo un pequeño problema con un selector que se genera utilizando PHP, dicho selector muestra el mes actual en formato "aaaamm" y los 5 meses anteriores. Para ello utilizó la función strtotime() con la que resto los meses a la fecha actual, el problema se da cuando llega el dia 29, 30 y 31 del mes. Por ejemplo en julio al restarle -5 meses debería llegar hasta febrero, pero actualmente muestra 2 veces marzo (usando -5 y -4 meses), asumo que es porque febrero no tiene 29, 30 o 31 y al no encontrarlo coloca marzo en ambos.

Lo que busco es que el usuario seleccione el mes que desea que el sitio cargue, entonces tomó la fecha actual como base para saber que periodo es el límite inferior restándole 5 meses, 4 y así sucesivamente.

¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Los meses los estoy generando así:

```
<?php 

$fecha = date("d-m-Y");

echo date('Ym',strtotime($fecha.'-5 months'))."</br>" ;
echo date('Ym',strtotime($fecha.'-4 months'))."</br>";
echo date('Ym',strtotime($fecha.'-3 months'))."</br>";
echo date('Ym',strtotime($fecha.'-2 months'))."</br>";
echo date('Ym',strtotime($fecha.'-1 months'))."</br>";
echo date("Ym",strtotime($fecha.'-24 hours'));
?>
```

Comment: No queda claro el propósito de tu código, que es lo fundamental en todo programa. ¿Qué debe hacer el código? Explícalo brevemente. ¿Cómo deben manejarse situaciones como cambio de año por ejemplo, cuando los meses pasan de un año a otro?

Comment: Si al final no importa el día del mes, ignóralo desde el inicio usando 1: `date("1-m-Y");`

Comment: @A.Cedano he editado la pregunta para intentar ser más explicitó.

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo una solución ***a la vieja usanza***.

De esta manera obtienes un resultado similar al que esperas. Quizás no es la solución más óptima pero funciona.

```
<?php
    #Obtiene el mes actual
    $mesActual = date("n");
    #Obtiene el año actual
    $anioActual = date("Y");
    
    #Muestra el mes actual
    echo ($anioActual."-".$mesActual."\n");
    #Recorre los 5 meses anteriores
    for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        #Decrementa el mes
        $mesAnterior = $mesActual - $i;
        #Si $mesAnterior es 0 o negativo, le suma el valor a 12
        $mes = ($mesAnterior < 1) ? 12 + $mesAnterior : $mesAnterior;
        #Si $mesAnterior es 0 o negativo, le le resta 1 al año actual
        $anio = ($mesAnterior < 1) ? $anioActual - 1 : $anioActual;
        #Muestra el listado de los 5 meses anteriores
        echo ($anio."-".$mes."\n");
    }
?>
```

En el mes actual ***Julio***, te devuelve este resultado:

```
2021-7
2021-6
2021-5
2021-4
2021-3
2021-2
```

Puedes probar poniendo un valor estático en `$mesActual = 3;` y te devuelve el siguiente resultado:

```
2021-3
2021-2
2021-1
2020-12
2020-11
2020-10
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar `DateInterval`, y `DateTime` para trabajar con fechas

```
<?php

$sub = 5;

$month = new DateInterval('P'.$sub.'M');
$month_ago = new DateTime();
$month_ago->sub($month);

echo($month_ago->format("Y-M-d"));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo más seguro para este tipo de situaciones es trabajar con objetos.

PHP cuenta con las clases [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php), [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php) y [`DatePeriod`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.dateperiod.php)  para generar con facilidad intervalos entre fechas.

Como podrás ver en el código haremos lo siguiente:

- Crearemos una fecha de partida que será *el primer día de este mes menos cinco meses*
- Crearemos una fecha de término que será *el mes actual*
- Crearemos un intervalo de un mes (`P1M`).
- Finalmente, con esos tres objetos crearemos un período que representará las fechas que necesitas. Aquí lo leeremos, imprimiremos in situ, pero también lo puedes guardar en un array para transportarlo a otro sitio o lo que quieras.

**Código:**

```
$fromDate = new DateTime('first day of this month - 5 months');
$toDate   = new DateTime('this month');
$theInterval  = new DateInterval('P1M'); 

$thePeriod = new DatePeriod($fromDate, $theInterval, $toDate);
foreach($thePeriod as $theDate) {
    echo $theDate->format('Ym').PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
202102
202103
202104
202105
202106
202107
```